# How to save/restore serializable object to/from file?

Tags: c#, serialization, stream

I have a list of objects and I need to save that somewhere in my computer. I have read some forums and I know that the object has to be `Serializable`. But it would be nice if I can get an example. For example if I have the following:

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeClass
{
     public string someProperty { get; set; }
}

SomeClass object1 = new SomeClass { someProperty = "someString" };
```

But how can I store `object1` somewhere in my computer and later retrieve?

Comment: Here's a tutorial that shows how to serialize to a file http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes an object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="serializableObject"></param>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    public void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName)
    {
        if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
                stream.Position = 0;
                xmlDocument.Load(stream);
                xmlDocument.Save(fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception here
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes an xml file into an object list
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T DeSerializeObject<T>(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) { return default(T); }

        T objectOut = default(T);

        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load(fileName);
            string xmlString = xmlDocument.OuterXml;

            using (StringReader read = new StringReader(xmlString))
            {
                Type outType = typeof(T);

                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(outType);
                using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(read))
                {
                    objectOut = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log exception here
        }

        return objectOut;
    }
```

Comment: Nice! Although `string attributeXml = string.Empty;` in `DeSerializeObject` is never used ;)

Comment: No need to call the close method on a reader within your using block. Dispose() is implicit and will take place even if an exception is raised within the block before the explicit Close(). Very useful block of code.

Comment: How to save a list of objects using this function I have used it but it is saving only the last object in my list

Comment: This method will not save internal or private fields, you can use this: https://github.com/mrbm2007/ObjectSaver

Answer (score 183):

I just wrote [a blog post on saving an object's data to Binary, XML, or Json](http://blog.danskingdom.com/saving-and-loading-a-c-objects-data-to-an-xml-json-or-binary-file/). You are correct that you must decorate your classes with the [Serializable] attribute, but only if you are using Binary serialization.  You may prefer to use XML or Json serialization. Here are the functions to do it in the various formats. See my blog post for more details.

**Update:** The [BinaryFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter) has been deprecated [for security reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) and should no longer be used.

### Binary

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes the given object instance to a binary file.
/// <para>Object type (and all child types) must be decorated with the [Serializable] attribute.</para>
/// <para>To prevent a variable from being serialized, decorate it with the [NonSerialized] attribute; cannot be applied to properties.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being written to the binary file.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to write the object instance to.</param>
/// <param name="objectToWrite">The object instance to write to the binary file.</param>
/// <param name="append">If false the file will be overwritten if it already exists. If true the contents will be appended to the file.</param>
public static void WriteToBinaryFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Reads an object instance from a binary file.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object to read from the binary file.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to read the object instance from.</param>
/// <returns>Returns a new instance of the object read from the binary file.</returns>
public static T ReadFromBinaryFile<T>(string filePath)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

### XML

Requires the System.Xml assembly to be included in your project.

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes the given object instance to an XML file.
/// <para>Only Public properties and variables will be written to the file. These can be any type though, even other classes.</para>
/// <para>If there are public properties/variables that you do not want written to the file, decorate them with the [XmlIgnore] attribute.</para>
/// <para>Object type must have a parameterless constructor.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being written to the file.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to write the object instance to.</param>
/// <param name="objectToWrite">The object instance to write to the file.</param>
/// <param name="append">If false the file will be overwritten if it already exists. If true the contents will be appended to the file.</param>
public static void WriteToXmlFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) where T : new()
{
    TextWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, append);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToWrite);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.Close();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Reads an object instance from an XML file.
/// <para>Object type must have a parameterless constructor.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object to read from the file.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to read the object instance from.</param>
/// <returns>Returns a new instance of the object read from the XML file.</returns>
public static T ReadFromXmlFile<T>(string filePath) where T : new()
{
    TextReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.Close();
    }
}
```

### Json

You must include a reference to Newtonsoft.Json assembly, which can be obtained from the [Json.NET NuGet Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json).

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes the given object instance to a Json file.
/// <para>Object type must have a parameterless constructor.</para>
/// <para>Only Public properties and variables will be written to the file. These can be any type though, even other classes.</para>
/// <para>If there are public properties/variables that you do not want written to the file, decorate them with the [JsonIgnore] attribute.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being written to the file.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to write the object instance to.</param>
/// <param name="objectToWrite">The object instance to write to the file.</param>
/// <param name="append">If false the file will be overwritten if it already exists. If true the contents will be appended to the file.</param>
public static void WriteToJsonFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) where T : new()
{
    TextWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        var contentsToWriteToFile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToWrite);
        writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, append);
        writer.Write(contentsToWriteToFile);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.Close();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Reads an object instance from an Json file.
/// <para>Object type must have a parameterless constructor.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object to read from the file.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to read the object instance from.</param>
/// <returns>Returns a new instance of the object read from the Json file.</returns>
public static T ReadFromJsonFile<T>(string filePath) where T : new()
{
    TextReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        var fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(fileContents);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.Close();
    }
}
```

### Example

```
// Write the contents of the variable someClass to a file.
WriteToBinaryFile<SomeClass>("C:\someClass.txt", object1);

// Read the file contents back into a variable.
SomeClass object1= ReadFromBinaryFile<SomeClass>("C:\someClass.txt");
```

Comment: I like your Binary serialization code.  But on WriteToBinaryFile why would you ever want to append to the file?  It seems you'd want to create a new file in all cases.  Otherwise there'd be a whole bunch of extra information on the deserialization.

Comment: @publicwireless Yeah, you are probably right. I didn't think about it much at the time; I just wanted the signatures of the 3 functions to match :P

Comment: using the append method, serializing many objects in the same file, how do I deserialize them? how do I seek in the stream?

Comment: Please add the comment to the binary serializer that will advise people that the resulting data is stamped with the strong name of the assembly and changes to versions of this without adding redirect bindings or running in environments which do not respect said bindings (e.g. powershell) will fail

Comment: @JohnDemetriou If saving multiple things to a file, I would recommend wrapping the objects in some form of context object and serializing that object (Let the object manager parse out the parts you want). If you are trying to save more data than you can hold in memory, you might want to switch to an object store (object database) instead of a file.

Comment: Will this serialize a stream? Let's say i have a model that contains 3 strings and a stream. Will the stream be saved to disk as well?

Comment: Serialize _Exception type_ (`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException`) with ***InnerExceptions***: `System.Net.WebException` and `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`?

Comment: Nice to have a quick how-to for each case. Could be made shorter and more idiomatic with `using(new *Writer(...)) { writer.Write()...); })` and so on, instead of the more verbose try/catch.

Comment: Are you sure @StéphaneGourichon? `using` calls `.Dispose()` which is not necessarily equivalent to `.Close()`. I haven't tested to confirm one way or the other.

Comment: @deadlydog yes, it's the recommended use. The `IDisposable` interface was created to standardize how to cleanup and reclaim resources. See for example [Using objects that implement IDisposable | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects "Using objects that implement IDisposable | Microsoft Docs").

Comment: CAUTIONARY NOTE on the "Binary" section: using `BinaryFormatter` is almost always a mistake; the number of times this should be used is *nearly* zero now, especially in the context of .NET Core and the future direction of .NET; virtually **anything else** would be a better choice than `BinaryFormatter` (except `NetDataContractSerializer`); personally I'd lean towards protobuf-net, but I'm hugely biased

Comment: What does this return at EOF?  I want to read in the entire file to a List so I using the binary version of function above, I can stop reading if it returns the C# equivalent of NULL.  C# noob here.

Answer (score 31):

You'll need to serialize to something: that is, pick binary, or xml (for default serializers) or write custom serialization code to serialize to some other text form.

Once you've picked that, your serialization will (normally) call a Stream that is writing to some kind of file.

So, with your code, if I were using XML Serialization:

```
var path = @"C:\Test\myserializationtest.xml";
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    XmlSerializer xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeClass));

    xSer.Serialize(fs, serializableObject);
}
```

Then, to deserialize:

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) //double check that...
{
    XmlSerializer _xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeClass));

    var myObject = _xSer.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

NOTE: This code hasn't been compiled, let alone run- there may be some errors.  Also, this assumes completely out-of-the-box serialization/deserialization.  If you need custom behavior, you'll need to do additional work.

Comment: This solution works fine and **without** the need of an **external library**. Just native .NET code. Still useful after 13 years. (-:

Answer (score 13):

## 1. Restore Object From File

From [Here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm)  you can deserialize an object from file in two way.

#### Solution-1: Read file into a string and deserialize JSON to a type

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\myObj.json");
MyObject myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```

#### Solution-2: Deserialize JSON directly from a file

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\myObj.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    MyObject myObj2 = (MyObject)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(MyObject));
}
```

## 2. Save Object To File

from [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonSerializerToFile.htm) you can serialize an object to file in two way.

#### Solution-1: Serialize JSON to a string and then write string to a file

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\myObj.json", json);
```

#### Solution-2: Serialize JSON directly to a file

```
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"c:\myObj.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(file, myObj);
}
```

## 3. Extra

You can download Newtonsoft.Json from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) by following command

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use JsonConvert from Newtonsoft library.
To serialize an object and write to a file in json format:

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
```

And to deserialize it back into object:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjType>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. Convert the json string to base64string and Write or append it to binary file.
2. Read base64string from binary file and deserialize using BsonReader.
**

```
 public static class BinaryJson
{
    public static string SerializeToBase64String(this object obj)
    {
        JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        MemoryStream objBsonMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (BsonWriter bsonWriterObject = new BsonWriter(objBsonMemoryStream))
        {
            jsonSerializer.Serialize(bsonWriterObject, obj);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(objBsonMemoryStream.ToArray());
        }           
        //return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(objBsonMemoryStream.ToArray());
    }
    public static T DeserializeToObject<T>(this string base64String)
    {
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
        using (BsonReader reader = new BsonReader(ms))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including external package like `Newtonsoft.Json`, you could use the new standard `System.Text.Json`.
Example code:

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace SerializeBasic
{
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureCelsius { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var weatherForecast = new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Parse("2019-08-01"),
                TemperatureCelsius = 25,
                Summary = "Hot"
            };

            string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast);

            Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
        }
    }
}
// output:
//{"Date":"2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00","TemperatureCelsius":25,"Summary":"Hot"}
```

For more information: [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0#how-to-write-net-objects-as-json-serialize)

Comment: Deserialize it with `weatherforecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(of Weatherforecast)(jsonString)`