# how do i save/load objects in a list collection In WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am quite new to programming and have been learning as i go. This program is just something i  am doing to learn more about what i can do in programming. I am using c# WPF. I have a program that when opens gives you a choice of two buttons, each opens a new window one to add animals to a list and the other to display the objects in the the list. but i can't find a way of saving the objects in the adding window and being able to load them when i restart the program? i have seen some thing about save dialog but i am not sure if this is what i need or?

Comment: There are many options here. One is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115721/how-to-save-restore-serializable-object-to-from-file (save to a file), another is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f92s97z.aspx (save to a SQL database).

Comment: Yea I would say try saving to a text file first.

Comment: Use Generics to Save like List,Dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first decide where to save your results. Database / XML File / Binary file / ??.

It seems like you are practicing C#, try persisting it to a file check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115721/how-to-save-restore-serializable-object-to-from-file,'link) link, has some good example.

Comment: this looks like just what i need from what i have read in the link have not seen anything about Serializable when i was looking for answers thank you.