# C# store subclasses to XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I want to make it easy to store lot of data into a XML file. Before I did it with structures and that worked well, but now I want to make use of classes, see my example below. when saving to XML, the subclasses are not saved to the XML.

In the XML file I see a bunch of

```
<logic>
<logicData xsi:nil="true" />
<logicData xsi:nil="true" />
<logicData xsi:nil="true" />
```

This is my current code that I use

```
  public class colorProfileSettings
{
    public int[] btn_background = new int[16];
    public int[] btn_input = new int[16];
    public int[] btn_press = new int[16];
}

public class logicData
{
    public colorProfileSettings[] colors = new colorProfileSettings[2];
    public int configBtnLedTest = 0;
    public int configBtnDimPlus = 0;
    public int configBtnDimMin = 0;
    public int configBtnCleaning = 0;
    public int configBtnDayNightToggle = 0;
    public int groupBg = 0;
    public int groupLedTest = 0;
    public int groupDimming = 10;
}

public class ClassConfigData
{
    public logicData[] logic = new logicData[100];
    public string fileLocName;
}

public ClassConfigData data = new ClassConfigData();

public void WriteXML(string fileLoc)
{
    try
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLoc))
        {
            XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassConfigData));
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@fileLoc);
            writer.Serialize(file, data);
            file.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Not a valid file selected.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save/restore serializable object to/from file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115721/how-to-save-restore-serializable-object-to-from-file)

Comment: Well what did you expect? You made an array of `100` empty elements.

Comment: Add `public ClassConfigData() { for (int i = 0; i < logic.Length; i++) { logic[i] = new logicData(); } }` inside `class ClassConfigData` and you'll see **very** different results.

Comment: You mention "subclasses", but there's not any sort of inheritance going on. Is there more to what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never instantiate any of the `logicData` array elements.

I changed your `ClassConfigData` class to the following, and your `logicData` class to the following, and it worked as expected.

```
public class ClassConfigData
{
    public logicData[] logic = new logicData[100];
    public string fileLocName;

    public ClassConfigData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < logic.Length; i++)
        {
            logic[i] = new logicData();
        }
    }
}

public class logicData
{
    public colorProfileSettings[] colors = new colorProfileSettings[2];
    public int configBtnLedTest = 0;
    public int configBtnDimPlus = 0;
    public int configBtnDimMin = 0;
    public int configBtnCleaning = 0;
    public int configBtnDayNightToggle = 0;
    public int groupBg = 0;
    public int groupLedTest = 0;
    public int groupDimming = 10;

    public logicData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
        {
            colors[i] = new colorProfileSettings();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I ran `WriteXML("test.xml");` and it did exactly what it should have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClassConfigData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <logic>
    <logicData>
      <colors>
        <colorProfileSettings>
          <btn_background>
            <int>0</int>
            ...
          </btn_background>
          ...
        </colorProfileSettings>
        ...
      </colors>
      <configBtnLedTest>0</configBtnLedTest>
      <configBtnDimPlus>0</configBtnDimPlus>
      <configBtnDimMin>0</configBtnDimMin>
      <configBtnCleaning>0</configBtnCleaning>
      <configBtnDayNightToggle>0</configBtnDayNightToggle>
      <groupBg>0</groupBg>
      <groupLedTest>0</groupLedTest>
      <groupDimming>10</groupDimming>
    </logicData>
    <logicData>
      <colors>
        <colorProfileSettings>
          <btn_background>
            <int>0</int>
            ...
          </btn_background>
          ...
        </colorProfileSettings>
        ...
      </colors>
      <configBtnLedTest>0</configBtnLedTest>
      <configBtnDimPlus>0</configBtnDimPlus>
      <configBtnDimMin>0</configBtnDimMin>
      <configBtnCleaning>0</configBtnCleaning>
      <configBtnDayNightToggle>0</configBtnDayNightToggle>
      <groupBg>0</groupBg>
      <groupLedTest>0</groupLedTest>
      <groupDimming>10</groupDimming>
    </logicData>
    ...
```

Also, **anytime** you create an array of a reference type (a `class`), then you **must** instance **each element of the array.** Otherwise, they are all `null`, and as such when serialized there will be no **sub-properties**, as they **do not exist yet!** The reason you did not have to do this with `structs` is because each time you create an array of `structure` types (which are **value types**), the `CLR` clears the memory of the array to new instances of the `struct` type for each element. This is also why in a `struct` you must specify a value for **every** property when you create a `constructor` in a `structure`.

The following code demonstrates this fact:

```
public struct StructureType
{
    public int number;
    public int otherNumber;
}

public class ClassType
{
    public int number;
    public int otherNumber;
}

StructureType[] s1 = new StructureType[2];
s1[0].number = 25;
ClassType[] c1 = new ClassType[2];
c1[0].number = 25;
```

You will get a `NullReferenceException` on the `c1[0].number = 25;` line, as `c1[0]` **does not exist.** But `s1[0].number = 25;` works as `s1[0]` is defaulted to all zero's in memory.

Comment: @user1439564 No problem, I added more information you may wish to read as well.