# Deserialise JSON file from disk directly to object

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, async-await

I'm trying to deserialise a JSON file from local disk into an object. I've got the following, but this only seems to work when downloading it from the web:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
using (var s = await client.GetStreamAsync(filePath))
using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    var js = new JsonSerializer();
    return js.Deserialize<MyObject>(jr);
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to do this, without first reading it into a string.

Comment: Any reason why you use HttpClient when you're reading from disk? HttpClient seems to only allow http-protocols.

Comment: I tried http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/performance.htm , and noticed it's not working (as you say). So I was wondering if there is a similar way to do this when reading from disk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save/restore serializable object to/from file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115721/how-to-save-restore-serializable-object-to-from-file)

Comment: Do you have to use HttpClient? Or is it an option to remove it?

Comment: @smoksnes no, don't have to

Comment: But I guess that the solution needs to be able to handle BOTH http and local disk?

Comment: No, we're only reading/writing our json from/to disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using (var s = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(s))
    {
        var js = new JsonSerializer();
        var obj = js.Deserialize<MyObject>(jr);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From [Here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm)
you can deserialize an object from file in two way.

#### Solution-1: Read file into a string and deserialize JSON to a type

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\myObj.json");
MyObject myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```

#### Solution-2: Deserialize JSON directly from a file

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"c:\myObj.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    MyObject myObj2 = (MyObject)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(MyObject));
}
```

You can download Newtonsoft.Json from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) by following command

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx

It's an MSDN article called "How to: Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data"