# C# How to read multiple json data in txt file

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Excuse me, I am a Rookie in C#.

I have a txt file like this

```
{"ID":1,"ScrewDiameter":28.0,"InjectionStroke":139.7,"InjectionVolume":86.0,"InjectionPressure":1857.0,"InjectionRate":62.0,"ClampForce":55.0,"MinMoldHeight":180.0,"MaxStroke":380.0,"InjectionSpeed":100.0,"CreateDate":null}
{"ID":2,"ScrewDiameter":36.0,"InjectionStroke":140.0,"InjectionVolume":143.0,"InjectionPressure":1842.0,"InjectionRate":90.0,"ClampForce":85.0,"MinMoldHeight":200.0,"MaxStroke":450.0,"InjectionSpeed":100.0,"CreateDate":null}
```

I want to get two data to show

but it shows

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.


於 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
於 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
於 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
於 Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
於 Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
於 Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
於 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
於 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
於 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
於 WindowsFormsAppgetData.Form1.ReadFromJsonFile[machine2](String filePath) 
於 C:\Users\Shih-Hao.Su\source\repos\WindowsFormsAppgetData\WindowsFormsAppgetData\Form1.cs: 行 50
```

'[13104] WindowsFormsAppgetData.exe' 程式以返回碼 -1 (0xffffffff) 結束。

I use this example

json

[How to save/restore serializable object to/from file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115721/how-to-save-restore-serializable-object-to-from-file)

and change 
   append = true

I expected results like

```
"ID":1,"ScrewDiameter":28.0,"InjectionStroke":139.7,"InjectionVolume":86.0,"InjectionPressure":1857.0,"InjectionRate":62.0,"ClampForce":55.0,"MinMoldHeight":180.0,"MaxStroke":380.0,"InjectionSpeed":100.0,"CreateDate":null
"ID":2,"ScrewDiameter":36.0,"InjectionStroke":140.0,"InjectionVolume":143.0,"InjectionPressure":1842.0,"InjectionRate":90.0,"ClampForce":85.0,"MinMoldHeight":200.0,"MaxStroke":450.0,"InjectionSpeed":100.0,"CreateDate":null
```

Comment: XML is not JSON

Comment: Make a class with the variables listed, and use the json

Comment: This format, commonly known as "ndjson", "newline delimited json", isn't supported out of the box by json.net. You will ned to read the contents of that file, one "line" at a time, and deserialize the resulting string to one object at a time.

Comment: sorry, I had wrong title. I am finding how to modify

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a file, I named it "json.json"

2) Put this array inside:

```
[{"ID":1,"ScrewDiameter":28.0,"InjectionStroke":139.7,"InjectionVolume":86.0,"InjectionPressure":1857.0,"InjectionRate":62.0,"ClampForce":55.0,"MinMoldHeight":180.0,"MaxStroke":380.0,"InjectionSpeed":100.0,"CreateDate":null},{"ID":2,"ScrewDiameter":36.0,"InjectionStroke":140.0,"InjectionVolume":143.0,"InjectionPressure":1842.0,"InjectionRate":90.0,"ClampForce":85.0,"MinMoldHeight":200.0,"MaxStroke":450.0,"InjectionSpeed":100.0,"CreateDate":null}]
```

3) Use this code:

```
List<dynamic> objs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(File.ReadAllText("json.json"));
```

Comment: thank you.but it shows
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException HResult=0x80131500 Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: If you follow my answer, it can't happen, if you get this error, it means you did it differently.

Comment: Check your input file here, it looks like whatever is being loaded starts with a '<', perhaps it is XML not JSON?