# Binary serialization of object to file with specific unicode

Tags: c#, serialization, unicode, binary, protobuf-net

I am trying to serialize/deserialize an object. 
The serialization works well, but the deserialization doesn't work. It seems that it is a unicode problem : There is a **System.Text.DecoderFallbackException** Exception that says that there is a Unicode problem (Translation French to English) :

```
Can not translate [FF] bytes to index 31 from the code page specified in Unicode.
```

I used the two functions for Binary serialization in [deadlydog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22417240/11560657) answer on the topic.

The question is, how can I specify a Unicode for deserialization and serialization in this code ?

---

**EDIT :**

Finaly I am using [protobuf-net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net), here are my functions :

```
    public static void WriteToBinaryFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false)
    {
        using (var file = File.Open(filePath, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create))
        {
            Serializer.Serialize<T>(file, objectToWrite);
        }
    }


    public static T ReadFromBinaryFile<T>(string filePath)
    {
        using (var file = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(file);
        }
    }
```

But I have an error when I deserialize : **Invalid field in source data: 0**

Comment: I kinda need to raise a red flag here; that linked post uses `BinaryFormatter`, which is **almost always** a ***terrible*** idea (the only time it *should* be used is for communicating between app-domains, or for IPC/RPC between systems *that are strongly tied and will always be in sync*). Using it for file persistence is a **really bad idea** and it **will hurt you**. Can I strongly suggest you revisit your serialization choices? If you want binary, tools like protobuf-net are *very easy to use*, and will **get this right**.

Comment: FWIW: the code shown shouldn't cause encoding errors; that's very odd and unusual - are you sure you didn't corrupt the payload at some point? (that's remarkably easy to do, I see people doing this *all the time*); this **is not an endorsement**, however, and even if it is this: I really really don't think that "fix the problem that is causing the corruption" is your best approach here; again, I **very strongly urge** you to run away from `BinaryFormatter` as fast as you possibly can, and do not look back.

Comment: (if you can show your usage *surrounding* this code, I can probably point out any likely causes of corruption; the most common cause is people trying to store binary as text by running it backwards through an `Encoding`, which ... doesn't work)

Comment: JSON is HTML which will not work with binary.   HTML has special characters.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references. You can use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) to convert special characters.  Also when sending over a html connection you need to make a 64 bit string to remove special characters.  The JSON serializer should handle special characters (unicode).  I do  not know what instruction the code is failing so I can't tell what the correct solution would be.

Comment: @jdweng um... unless I'm missing something, everything about that statement is wrong, sorry; "JSON is HTML" - I'm guessing you actually meant "text" there? ... "which will not work with binary." - no, text works trivially with binary; that's what an encoding defines, and `BinaryFormatter` (which is doing the work here) knows perfectly well how to encode/decode text/strings; "when sending over a html connection" - do you mean http? http works fine with binary; nobody mentioned JSON/HTML, btw; "you need to make a 64 bit string" - just; no; that's "not even wrong"

Comment: The deadlydog has JSON.  Marc this is absolutely wrong : " http works fine with binary".  You MUST encode to 64 base string to send binary over HTTP.

Comment: @jdweng the linked post has examples for binary, xml, and json; we're discussing the first one here; "base-64" != "64-bit" (if anything it is 128-bit i.e. ASCII), but if you mean base-64, no: that's also backwards; HTTP (not that anyone mentioned HTTP being involved here) - despite the T being "text" - works just fine with raw binary without any encoding - that's actually how most non-text content is transmitted; if you want to send binary *inside text content* (like in HTML), then yes: you need to use something like base-64, base-16, or similar; but *nobody is talking about those things*

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try using protobuf-net !

Comment: @MarcGravell, I think I am doing alright, I did exactly as it is said in the documentation in github. But I have an error when I deserialize : **Invalid field in source data: 0**. I have seen some topic on this, but they are not doing like me (writing to a file)

Comment: @lema "Invalid field in source data: 0" - are you talking about protobuf-net ? fields must be **positive** integers (and low numbers are cheaper than high numbers): start with `[ProtoMember(1)]` etc

Comment: Yes I am talking about protobuf-net ! I believe all my fields are positive integers.

Comment: I have some class that in inherit from others, maybe there is some rules that I don't know ? I have added ProtoInclude as it is said in the documentation.

Comment: @lema I can definitely help you with this - I'm the library author; but I'd need to see some code

Comment: Well there is too much code/class in my project, bu I'll edit my post to give you my serialization/deserialization functions.

Comment: @lema I only found this now because I remembered to check; if you don't "at" me, I don't get a notification. I see those methods, and they look fine. Can you post enough code for me to actually repro the issue you're seeing? I..e something runnable? Help me to help you. ..

Comment: @MarcGravell I finaly used JsonSerializer and it worked well immediatly, it would have been too long to add all my code (around 10 class need to be serialize). But thanks a lot for trying to help me !