# c# how to save list to xml with list child List<string, Class>

Tags: c#

How to convert this:

```
public class Person
    {   
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Age{ get; set; }
    }

public class SectionList
    {
        public List<Person> PersonList { get; set; }
        public string SectionName { get; set; }
    }


public static List<SectionList> sectionList = new List<SectionList>();
```

into this XML:

```
  <SectionList>    
    <SectionName>1</SectionName>
    <PersonList>
      <Person>
       <Name>Ace</Name>
       <Age>30</Age>
      </Person>
      <Person>
       <Name>Zeus</Name>
       <Age>2</Age>
      </Person>
    </PersonList>
  </SectionList>
```

It took me about 6 hours to find and experiment.  But not yet successful Please help.
Or something else, but must show PersonList too

This code i got But the result was not what I wanted
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6115782/8902883

```
public void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName)
{
    if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

    try
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
            stream.Position = 0;
            xmlDocument.Load(stream);
            xmlDocument.Save(fileName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log exception here
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfSectionList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SectionList>
    <PersonList />
    <SectionName>1</SectionName>
  </SectionList>
  <SectionList>
    <PersonList />
    <SectionName>2</SectionName>
  </SectionList>
</ArrayOfSectionList>
```

//

Thank you so much, it's my mistake.
After I add a "Person" to the" SectionList"

```
SectionList.Add (Person)
Person.Clear();
```

"SectionName" remains, but all "Person" is missing.
Now I fixed it. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can try to refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization#serializing-a-class-that-contains-a-field-returning-a-complex-object

Answer (score 2):

you have made certain mistakes while implementing the code and I am assuming that you have used some xml librabry.

your code should be like below to bind with your models.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Person")]
    public class Person 
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Age")]
        public string Age { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName="PersonList")]
   public class PersonList 
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName="Person")]
       public List<Person> Person { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName="SectionList")]
   public class SectionList 
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName="SectionName")]
       public string SectionName { get; set; }
    
       [XmlElement(ElementName="PersonList")]
       public PersonList PersonList { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Reference: https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 2):

Try following which eliminates one tag like your original posting:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Root root = new Root() {
                SectionList =  new List<SectionList>() {
                    new SectionList()
                    {
                        SectionName = "1",
                        PersonList = new List<Person>() {
                            new Person() { Name = "Ace", Age = "30"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, root);
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {   
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Age{ get; set; }
    }
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement()]
        public List<SectionList> SectionList { get; set; }
    }

    public class SectionList
    {
        [XmlElement("Person")]
        public List<Person> PersonList { get; set; }
        public string SectionName { get; set; }

    }


    
}
```